# Parametrize Connections from Database parametrization table

Tags: database-connection, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

We are using Pentaho Data Integration V7 working with multiple data origins with an Oracle DWH destiny.

We have stored all the connection access data in a parametrization table, let's call it : D_PARAM. All the connections are configured using parameters (${database_name} ... etc)

We have , at the begining of every job , a transformation with a "set variables" step which reads the right parameters from D_PARAM.

This all works fine, my problem is :

Every time we want to edit a single transformation, or in the development process of a new one , we can't use the paremetrized connections because the parameters haven't been setted. We need then to use "hardcoded" connections during the development process.

Is there a better way to manage this situation ? The idea of having the connections parametrized is to avoid errors and simplify the connections management, but if at the end we need both kind of connections.. I don't see them so useful.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a simple answer, you could rotate your kettle.properties file to change default values, you keep all the values in the file:

```
D_PARAM = DBN
D_PARAM_DB1 = DB1
D_PARAM_DB2 = DB2
...
```

And just update the D_PARAM with the one you need from the different D_PARAM_DBN before starting PDI. It's a hassle to be constantly updating the kettle.properties file, but works out of the box.

You could also try working with environments, for this you would have to install a plugin available in Github: https://github.com/mattcasters/kettle-environment, it was created by a former PDI developer, and I don't know if it works with v7 version, it was updated to work with 8.2, but it would probably work with v7, to test it, you can install your PDI version on another directory on your PC and install there the plugin (and other additional plugins you have in your current installation), so you don't break your setup. This blog entry gives you details on how to use the environments: http://diethardsteiner.github.io/pdi/2018/12/16/Kettle-Environment.html

I don't know if the environments plugin would solve your problem, because you can't change the environment in the middle of a job, but for me, with the maitre script to use the environments when I program a job or transform, it's been easier to work with different projects/paths in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

In Spoon you can click on the “Edit” menu and “Set environment variables”. It’ll list all variables currently in use and you can set their values. Then the transformation will use those values when you run.

Also works in Preview, but it’s somewhat buggy, it doesn’t always take updated values.